# check_logfiles - Howto check logfile with random direcotry

Tags: nagios

I want to monitor a logfile. The directory is created everyday.

The path is as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\PMM\logs\backup-2020-03-28-23-00-09-939\backup.log"
```

The problem is the timestamp in directory name.
How must the config file be defined to check this directory?

Best regards
Steve

Answer (score 0):

if you only monitor that the file exists, you could try to make a plugin in bash, perl, python, etc that monitor the directory using the date as a variable name of the folder where the log file exists.